# How to get a script or a file from an svn repo and execute it

Tags: svn, repository

I know there are commands like `svn cp`, `svn update` but I am actually confused.

Answer (score 0):

Use `svn export`. It will download just the file without any additional SVN garbage, unlike `svn checkout`.

Comment: I see. Thank you. @blagovest buyukliev

suppose i have this script:
svn export http://samplesource/dummyscript.sh
svn commit -username --password

.dummyscript.sh

--------
would this script download and execute the script from svn?